# Greedy pattern matching in typed racket

Tags: typed-racket

I'm looking to match an arbitrary length list of patterns in typed/racket.

A simple example of what I'm trying to do is the following expression:

```
(match '(1 2 3) [(list (? real? n) ...) n])
```

In untyped racket, I would expect the following result:

```
'(1 2 3)
```

However, the type checker throws the following error:

```
`Type Checker: Error in macro expansion -- insufficient type information to typecheck. please add more type annotations in: (match (quote (1 2 3)) ((list (? real? n) ...) n))`
```

What is the best way to provide typing information when using `...` to perform greedy pattern matching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further experimentation, it appears that the output of the match needs some typing information associated with it. For example, the following works:

```
((lambda (l) : Any
         (match l [(list (? real? n) ...) n]))
  '(1 2 3))
```